# Rewriting app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php

Tags: module, magento-1, overrides, controllers

I am trying to rewrite `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php`. In my config.xml I have the following:

```
<frontend>
  <routers>
    <catalog>
      <args>
        <modules>
          <Slice_CustomCompare before="Mage_Catalog">Slice_CustomCompare_Catalog_Product_Compare</Slice_CustomCompare>
        </modules>
      </args>
    </catalog>
  </routers>
</frontend>
```

and in `app/code/local/Slice/CustomCompare/controllers/Product/CompareController.php` I have:

```
<?php
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Catalog').DS.'CompareController.php');
class Slice_CustomCompare_Product_CompareController extends Mage_Catalog_Product_CompareController {

  public function removeAction() {
    Mage::log('Slice_CustomCompare_Product_CompareController:removeAction');
  }
}
?>
```

When I try to remove a product from the compare list I don't get `Slice_CustomCompare_Product_CompareController:removeAction` in my logs. Instead I get output that I added to the method in the core code. What am I missing? Why is my rewrite not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your config section should look like this:

```
<frontend>
  <routers>
    <catalog>
      <args>
        <modules>
          <Caupo_CustomCompare before="Mage_Catalog">Caupo_CustomCompare</Caupo_CustomCompare>
        </modules>
      </args>
    </catalog>
  </routers>
</frontend>
```

This means that Magento looks for a controller in `Caupo/CustomCompare/controllers` before looking in `Mage/Catalog/controllers`.
The controller path must follow the same file path as the original controller (but looks like you already have that:)

```
Mage /Catalog      /controllers/Product/CompareController.php - original controller
Caupo/CustomCompare/controllers/Product/CompareController.php - your controller
\____/\____________/\________________________________________/
   |       |                          |
   |       |                          |---Common path to controller
   |       |--- Module
   |---- Namespace
```

And your require statement should be like this:

```
require_once('Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php');
```

I think it works with this also but I'm not sure:

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Catalog').DS.'controllers'.DS.'Product'.DS.'CompareController.php');
```